# Android Studio / ¿Por que mis imágenes no logran ocupar todo el ancho?

Tags: android, android-studio, glide, image-view

**Descripción**

Tengo una **ImageView** con width="match_parent" a la cual se le carga por medio de una **URL** con la librería **Glide** una imágen de 6.000px x 6.000px.

**Problema**

No se por que, como dice el título, no puedo lograr que esta ocupe todo el ancho, a pesar de la imágen que se le carga.

**Datos extra**

Probe con imágenes de otras dimensiones (por ej. 1900x1080) y se siguen ajustando hasta el mismo punto, dejando los bordes izquierdo y derecho vacíos.

**Adjunto una imágen de como se ve**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Adjunto el código xml de la imágen**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_img_materia"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_materia"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adjunto el código Java de la librería Glide**

```
Glide.with(info_clases.this).load("https://preview.redd.it/f2j745lex6311.png?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=b4b4bbe2f22d64fd25c21e4e7217c4bff0446510")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.img_loading).error(R.drawable.img_error).into(img_materia);
```

**Gracias por leer**

Comment: Hola Tomas , el problema es en el contenedor, agrega el contenedor padre del ImageView.

Comment: Hola Tomas, podrias agregar el contenedor que contiene el contenedor padre del ImageView, en algun lado tienen que estar esos bordes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu `ImageView` tienes definido `android:layout_width="match_parent"` lo cual es correcto.

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_materia"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda" />
```

pero si no abarca todo el ancho de tu dispositivo esto se debe a que el contenedor de este `ImageView` no tiene definido  `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

---

**Actualización:** 
Analizando la url que proporcionas hay algo que es importante comentar, la url tiene una propiedad `&crop=smart` que al parecer escala con respecto a la altura la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es por esa razón que cuando la agregas a tu `ImageView` esta no abarca todo el ancho ya que de otra forma perdería el aspecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debes realizar es definir a tu `ImageView` un scaleType, puedes usar `android:scaleType="fitXY"` que escala la imagen en las coordenadas X y Y .

```
<ImageView
     ...
     ...
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     .../>
```

pero esta propiedad puede modificar el aspecto de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Lo ideal sería usar `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` para que la imagen no se distorsione y mantenga su aspecto pero esta se contenga dentro del `ImageView`**:

```
<ImageView
     ...
     ...
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     .../>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edité la pregunta con el padre

Comment: Espera Tomas,veo estas usando Constrainlayout, ahí sería bueno conocer que restricciones tienen los contenedores principales, que tienes afuera de RelativeLayout @TomasM

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por responder. Lo pude solucionar con scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: @TomasM ayer detecte que la url tiene una propiedad "&crop=smart" lo que esta realizando es que mantiene el aspecto de la imagen y la escala con respecto a la altura, en este caso te sugiero usar  android:scaleType="centerCrop" para que el aspecto de la imagen no se distorsione, puedes usar también fitXY pero en algunas imagenes podrás notar que no es correcto como se muestran, saludos.